# Return data from API based on date/Amazon slot type

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I'm writing a Lambda function that gets data from an API for an Alexa Skill, but I want to make the results more specific by using Amazon's built-in `AMAZON.DATE` slot type. For example, only returning events for a specific date.

Function:

```
switch(event.request.intent.name) {
  case "GetTodaysPerfs":
    var endpoint = "http://services-app.lincolncenter.org/api/v1/event?dateFrom=2017-06-11T04%3A00%3A00.0Z&dateTo=2017-06-12T04%3A00%3A00.0Z"
    var body = ""
    http.get(endpoint, (response) => {
      response.on('data', (chunk) => { body += chunk })
      response.on('end', () => {
        var data = JSON.parse(body)
        var perfs = data.data[0].show.title
        context.succeed(
          generateResponse(
            buildSpeechletResponse(`The following performances are on today: ${perfs}`, true),
            {}
          )
        )
      })
    })
    break;

  default:
    throw "Invalid intent"
}
```

I can achieve more specific results by manually specifying a date range in the endpoint URL, but obviously, this isn't ideal as it's not dynamic.

I'm new to working with APIs, but I have a few ideas:

1. Contstruct the endpoint URL on the fly using `AMAZON.DATE`
2. Loop through the `data` objects and filter based on `data.dateRange` for each event

For better performance, I'm leaning towards the first since the default data is very large. Which would be the best solution for me and how could I achieve it?

Please let me know if I can provide anymore useful info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to let the user specify the date, then include a slot for the date in the intent. As you have identified, this slot will be of type AMAZON.DATE.

Then in your intent handler, test that the slot has valid data, and use it in your request.

Refer to the Alexa doc (eg.[this link](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference)) for details on slots (sounds like you've already read this) and search on 'alexa slot example' (eg. [this link](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-howto/blob/master/src/index.js)) for help on the code to access the slot data.

It sounds like you're on the right track with the 1st approach.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I'm just trying to access the slot data, but can't seem to. I tried defining `var todaySlot = this.request.intent.slots.Today.value` above my `data` variable, but it didn't return the date. Does it need its own function?